# To much re-directions on local dev environment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, webserver, wamp

I have a local dev environment, just a wamp install on windows 7 32-bit.

Now my problem is that I have existing project content witch want to redirect a lot. With .htaccess and shit. My local web-server is not taking this an gives a:

> Fout 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): Er zijn te veel omleidingen.
>
> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): To many re-directions - *I have my error in dutch I guess this is the English version*

Now there is nothing wrong with my cookies. It tells me to check that.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost\.?(:[0-9]+)?$ 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=404,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

# -[PHP.INI OVERRIDE]-  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
php_value register_globals 0

# -[UPLOAD MAX FILE SIZE]-  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_execution_time 120


# -[ERROR REPORTING]-  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Complete error reporting
# php_value error_reporting 8191
# Zend error reporting
# php_value error_reporting 128
# Basic error reporting
  php_value error_reporting 8
# Minimal error reporting  
# php_value error_reporting 1

# -[ERROR DOCS]-  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?mode=error&type=403
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?mode=error&type=404
 ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?mode=error&type=500

# -[BESTAAT BESTAND -> DOORGEVEN] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [QSA,NC,L]

# -[CMS]---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 RewriteRule ^cms/$ cms/ [QSA,L]

# -[GLOBAL]- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 RewriteRule ^error/403$ index.php?mode=error&type=403 [L]
 RewriteRule ^error/404$ index.php?mode=error&type=404 [L]
 RewriteRule ^error/500$ index.php?mode=error&type=500 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*).html$ index.php?mode=$1&mode2=$2&mode3=$3&html=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*)/$                   index.php?mode=$1&mode2=$2&mode3=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*).html$               index.php?mode=$1&mode2=$2&html=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9@a-z_-]*)/$                                index.php?mode=$1&mode2=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)/([0-9a-z_-]*).html$                             index.php?mode=$1&html=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*)/$                                               index.php?mode=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_-]*).html$                                           index.php?html=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is the URL of the pages that fail? Also instead of the regexes on the bottom I suggest you just send the entire `REQUEST_URI` to *index.php* and parse the path there. Only heads up is that you must redirect to a 404 page manually if you can't parse the path, but that shouldn't be much of a fuzz. For example you could do `RewriteRule . index.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` on the bottom.

Comment: Its a local web-server so the URL is localhost. Then I need to go to localhost/login/?cms Then it gives me the error.

Comment: Is there anything else in the apache error log? Otherwise maybe try to debug using the **[R]** flag to see where the rewrites are made

Comment: I solved it! The wamp configuration Wants me to put everything behind root. So if I put everything inside root its before its root and if I put it behind the root its inside its own root. Like this /www has to contain the wamp index.php with has to be the index of your local work space and /www/myprojectroot, /www/myotherprojectroot, etc. is the place where I can put my projects. When call to the root path wamp skips /www so the next directory becomes the root. strange but true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling to Rooth path etc. Wamp skips the root (/www) To the folder behind that. So do not delete the wamp generated files and when you have a project you need to run local for testing on wamp create a folder inside /www like /www/myproject. Wamp makes that folder the root.

It literal does this when calling a magical constant in php like root_path:

<del>/www</del>/myproject